# AIR ADT duplicates icons in package

Tags: android, ios, air, adt

## Setup

**[According to documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7ff6)**, the icons that are specified in application `descriptor-app.xml` have to be relative to application root, and are not automatically added to the package.

> The path specified is relative to the application root directory.
>
> **Note:** The icons specified are not automatically added to the AIR package. The icon files must be included in their correct relative locations when the application is packaged.

The documentation itself provides an example using an `icons` folder

```
<icon> 
   <image16x16>icons/smallIcon.png</image16x16> 
   <image32x32>icons/mediumIcon.png</image32x32> 
   <image48x48>icons/bigIcon.png</image48x48> 
   <image128x128>icons/biggestIcon.png</image128x128>  
</icon>
```

I would include this folder in my application root with the following ADT command:
`adt [STUFF] outputfile.apk descriptor-app.xml main.swf icons`

## Result

This in turn produces the following package structure<sup>1</sup> (not listing irrelevant paths):

```
 package.apk
  |---> assets (this is the application root on Android package)
  |      |---> icons
  |      |      |---> smallIcon.png
  |      |      |---> mediumIcon.png
  |      |      |---> bigIcon.png
  |      |      |---> biggestIcon.png
  |      |---> main.swf
  |---> res
         |---> drawable-hdpi
         |      |---> icon.png
         |---> drawable-ldpi
         |      |---> icon.png
         |---> drawable-mdpi
         |      |---> icon.png
         |---> drawable-xhdpi
                |---> icon.png
```

<sup>1 Actual translation of size to path [as detailed here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html)</sup>

## Problem

The icons in folder under `res/drawable*` are **duplicates** of icons under `assets/icons`. The "drawable" folders are the Android package specific structure. From what I understand, `adt` command will take the icons specified in the `descriptor-app.xml` and place them in the correct place in the package, dependent on package type (iOS icons are located differently within the package then Android icons).

**What I don't understand is: *why do I have to include the `icons` folder in my application root?***

`adt` knows where the icons need to end up, but the `descriptor-app.xml` requires that icon path is specified relative to "application root".

On iOS this is *kinda* solvable<sup>2</sup> by renaming the icons to their final names and placing them in *correct* location within the package, because the `ipa` structure places icons within the **same context as application root**.

But on Android, this is not even possible, because the `apk` structure places icons **outside the application root context**, and `adt` won't let me add files to package outside the application root.

Yet, the documentation tells me something that is outright impossible for `apk` packages:

> The icon files must be included in their correct relative locations when the application is packaged.

<sup>2 Manually renaming icons for iOS and placing them in *correct* application root position is not ideal either, as `adt` already knows how to do that, and I as a user can make a mistake</sup>

So back to the question: why do I have to include `icons` folder in the application for it to be used correctly? I am not including `descriptor-app.xml` in the application (yet `adt` places it into correct package location, per OS, by itself), but why force me to include redundant copy of `icons`?

Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had been fixed in latest AIR SDK 21.0 Beta 21.0.0.150.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4100164

Comment: Only took 2 years :) Thanks for logging the bug, grats on first accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember from the docs and the text in the `app.xml` file, the app icons don't have to be in the app root (`src`) directory, just that the *reference* to them in the `app.xml` must be *relative* to the `src` directory. Additionally, the app root/`src` directory is automatically embedded in the file, which is why they are in your compiled app's root.

With that in mind, I have two possible solutions.

1. Use `../` notation. Move your icon folders from the `src` directory to the project's directory, meaning it won't be embedded by the compiler. When you use `icons/biggestIcon.png`, it's actually telling it `src/icons/biggestIcon.png`. `/` notation goes down one directory, `./` notation is the current directory, and `../` notation goes up one directory. So `src/../icons/biggestIcon.png` would go to `src`'s parent directory (the project directory). I've never tested this and I am unsure if it will accept that notation, but theoretically it should work.
2. In Flash Builder, you can go `Project > Properties` and under `Flex Build Packaging` there should be one menu for each of the platforms you are targeting. Go to `Package Contents` and deselect your icons folder for at least Android. This might be the better route, as it would allow you to handle iOS and Android separately. I believe the menu is worded differently in AS3 projects, but I believe it is still there and behaves the same.

Again, I haven't tested either of these so I cannot be 100% sure it will work. But these are the two methods I would attempt to solve the double embed issue (that I wasn't even aware of until now, so I am sure I will test these for my next project). Hopefully that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: I am not using Flex. I don't have a `src` folder. No `app root/src` is automatically embedded anywhere. I've tried all sorts of parent directories with `../`. Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately that doesn't help